# Find value of product

Tags: logarithms, algebraic-number-theory

Given that $5^a = 6, 6^b = 7, 7^c=8, 8^d=9, ...., 24^t=25$
Then what is the value of the product $abcdef...st$

I have tried taking log and multiplying. But my solution isn't matching the answer key which says answer is $ 5$

Taking log on both sides, we get $ a log5 = log 6, b log 6 = log 7$
This gives
$ a= log6/log5, b=log7/log6$ and so on. 
Multiplying them, we should get $abcdef...rst = log25/log5 = 2$

Comment: Well, if $5^a=6$ then $6^b=\left(5^a\right)^b=5^{ab}=7$ so...  Note:  I'm not getting $5$ as the answer here either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the log gives 
$$a \log(5) = \log(6), b \log(6) = \log(7), c \log(7) = \log(8), d \log(8) = \log(9), ..., t \log(24) = \log(25)
$$
I'm not sure what you might want to multiply in this situation, but my urge would be to first divide:
$$a = \frac{\log(6)}{\log(5)}, \,\, b = \frac{\log(7)}{\log(6)}, \,\,c = \frac{\log(8)}{\log(7)}, \,\, d = \frac{\log(8)}{\log(7)}, \,\,...\,\, t = \frac{\log(25)}{\log(24)}
$$
And now I do get a very strong urge to multiply:
$$abcd...t = \frac{\log(25)}{\log(5)} = 2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

we have:
$$
5^{a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot \cdots a_{24}}=25 = 5^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

you can write $$abcd\cdot ...\cdot st=\frac{\ln(6)}{\ln(5)}\cdot \frac{\ln(7)}{\ln(6)}\cdot \frac{\ln(8}{\ln(7)}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{\ln(25)}{\ln(24)}=...$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd have said the answer was $2$.

$$5^a=6\implies 6^b=\left(5^a\right)^b=5^{ab}=7$$

Similarly, $$5^{ab}=7\implies 7^c=\left(5^{ab}\right)^c=5^{abc}=8$$

Continuing in this way we arrive at $$5^{ab\cdots st}=25\implies ab\cdots st=2$$